# Error running gradle bootrun

Tags: spring, gradle, bootrun

I am trying to do gradle bootRun using IntelliJ, but this error appears:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
 Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

In the Console I have this:

```
2017-06-21 10:13:54.177  INFO 12008 --- [           main] com.nice_system.nicemedia.ApplicationKt  : Starting ApplicationKt on DESKTOP-GHI2UHL with PID 12008 (started by Darja Strahlberg in C:\Users\Darja Strahlberg
\code\versuch\nto_niceMediaServer)
2017-06-21 10:13:54.182  INFO 12008 --- [           main] com.nice_system.nicemedia.ApplicationKt  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-21 10:13:54.310  INFO 12008 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5be6e01c: start
up date [Wed Jun 21 10:13:54 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-21 10:13:56.234  INFO 12008 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean:
 class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$Ena
bleWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfigurat
ion$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframew
ork.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/re
st/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-06-21 10:13:57.102  INFO 12008 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframe
work.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc898557] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-21 10:13:57.776  INFO 12008 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2017-06-21 10:13:57.797  INFO 12008 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-21 10:13:57.800  INFO 12008 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-21 10:13:58.025  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-21 10:13:58.025  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3719 ms
2017-06-21 10:13:58.319  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-21 10:13:58.325  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-21 10:13:58.325  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-21 10:13:58.325  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-21 10:13:58.325  INFO 12008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally u
nnecessary.
2017-06-21 10:14:00.929 ERROR 12008 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.1.2"
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg" version "1.1.2"
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.1.2"

id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.3.RELEASE"}

jar {
baseName = 'nicemedia-api'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"

compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"

testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"

runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Refresh your Gradle dependencies. Check if mysql server is running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai it somehow cannot connect to your DB

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I had a problem with my DB! I have restarted the DB - and now it working!